# How to translate “as long as”?

Tags: anglais, expressions, indications-de-temps, conjonctions

I'm not sure how to translate this, as in *As long as I eat right, I'll stay healthy*.

I could in theory easily use the French the equivalent of *if I continue to* but that phrase doesn't quite have the same meaning. For me if I hear *if I continue to* I assume the speaker is already doing the action. But one doesn't automatically make that assumption with *as long as*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can translate it by *tant que* or *aussi longtemps que*. Which would give “*Tant que je mange bien, je reste en bonne santé*” for your sentence.

Comment: Future tense may be more accurate: « Tant que je mange bien, je resterai en bonne santé ». Present tense has a more "urgent" feel to an eventual failure: it suggests health will fail as soon as one stops eating right. Future tense suggests there will be a fuzzier transition.

Answer (score 12):

Une traduction possible est 'Du moment que'.

Comment: Pas seulement possible mais dans le cas présenté c'est la meilleure.

Comment: @Laure Je ne suis pas trop d'accord. Il me semble que "du moment que" ne traduit pas assez la notion de continuité présente dans "as long as" et "tant que".

Comment: @jlliagre: Dans l'exemple donné par le PO *as long as* n'implique pas forcément de notion de continuité mais une condition. On pourrait le remplacer ici le remplacer par *provided that/ on condition that*. Si le PO avait employé le présent et pas *will* dans la principale je n'aurais même pas dit « forcément ».

Comment: @Laure L'action de se nourrir étant forcément répétitive, la notion de continuité est implicite, dVyper fait d'ailleurs référence à "I continue to" dans sa question. On ne retrouve pas cet aspect dans "Du moment que" qui n'introduit qu'une condition comme le ferait "Puisque".

Answer (score 0):

Cela dépend du contexte qu'on l'utilise. As long as peut traduire par "tant que, pourvu que, a condition que , etc".

Answer (score 0):

Alternative à "tant que": "Pour aussi longtemps que".

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language Stack Exchange. Is this contribution intended as a comment or as an answer? If it is intended as an answer, please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Centre and improve your answer, e.g. by adding example sentences and fuller explanations.

Answer (score -1):

Une autre traduction possible serait : « Dès lors que », mais ce n'est pas la meilleure dans ce contexte.